# Set maximum execution time

Tags: jquery

I have a function in jquery where there is a while loop which can take a few seconds to finish. In Chrome th script runs fast, but in Firefox the same script blocks the UI thread too long. So I would like to set a timeout to this function, if it's not finished in one second then I exit it. Is is possible to do it in jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

```
var count = 1;
var counter = setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer() {
    if (count <= 0) {
        clearInterval(counter);
        return;
    }
    count = count - 1;
   //Runs code
}
```

below code will timeout after 1000 milisecond.

(i understand mistake)

Comment: But according to this page : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp, with setTimeout the code will be executed AFTER 1000 milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I've solved it by doing this :

```
var n = 0;

setTimeout(function() {
    n = 1;
}, 1000);
```

And in my while loop I check if n == 0